# Brute force searching

Tags: java, performance

I'm currently working on a natural language processing project and I have two `ArrayLists<String>` where each `ArrayList` contains a verb at index 0, a noun at index 1 and a noun at index 2 (repeat). I'm trying to find any two nouns in the first list that is present consecutively in the second by using:

```
 for(int i = 1; i<finalKnowledgeGraph.size(); i+=3) {
      for(int j = 1; j<finalKnowledgeGraph.size(); j+=3) {
           for(int k=1; k<storeAsserions.size(); k+=3) {
               if(finalKnowledgeGraph.get(i).equals(storeAsserions.get(k)) && finalKnowledgeGraph.get(j+1).equals(storeAsserions.get(k+1))){
                   System.out.println("Found one");
               } else if(finalKnowledgeGraph.get(i+1).equals(storeAsserions.get(k)) && finalKnowledgeGraph.get(j).equals(storeAsserions.get(k+1))) {
                   System.out.println("Found another");
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this code has cubic complexity and both `ArrayList`s are thousands of lines long. I'm wondering if anyone has any tips on how I could go about speeding up this process. Also, I know virtually nothing about optimization so if you do have some help please break it down relatively simply.
One of my friends recently suggested a HashMap and searching through that but in my head that's simply pushing the search problem from one data-structure to another

Comment: Look up how [search engines do it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach would benefit from sorted inputs.

But an even simpler approach would be to ignore the irrelevant verbs and rephrase the problem like this:

> A noun phrase is a pair of nouns. We are given two input sets of noun phrases, and must compute [set intersection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-), using a problem specific notion of "phrase equality".

This implies a linear O(n) input pre-processing pass, where you populate a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) with each input phrase, X+" "+Y.

With that in hand, your task is trivial. Scan the other collection of phrases, and for each phrase make two set membership queries: is X+" "+Y or Y+" "+X present in the set?

BTW, your identifier storeAsserions seems to be a typo for storeAssertions. And please include a space after keywords like `if` & `for`.